# Adding Secure web services to a custom JS Web App

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-service, mapproxy

I am building a JS web app using Esri's SDKs. I need to add a web tile services from map proxy. But the services need HTTP authentication. Based on my research I found out that the services are published in ArcGIS Server but are accessed through the map proxy. I have very limited knowledge of the map proxy. I am really confused how I can add those layer in my app. Do I need authorization code? If so where should I look for the one.